# What is the problem in my code how to style my code properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What is the problem in my code how to style my code properly I want that the frontend developer text and ReactJS website text move upside a little big I am a beginner I am learning from course, and they have given this exercise to do I have almost completed it just this text is not styling properly pls anyone tell how to style it properly you all can also check my code I will provide you

[image]

React file code

```
import React from 'react'
import './Info.css';
import About from './About';
import logo from './logo.jpg';
import Interest from './Interest';
import Socail from './Socail';

function Info() {
    return (
        <><img src={logo} /><div className='info-body'>
            <h1 className='name-text'>React learner</h1>
            <div className='small-t'>
            <p className='pos'>Frontend Developer</p>
            <small>reactjs.website</small>
            </div>
            <button className='e-button'>Email</button>
        </div>
        <About/>
        <Interest/>
        <Socail/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Info
```

css file code

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 317px;
    height: 317px;
    left: 116px;
    top: 44px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.info-body {
    position: absolute;
    width: 317px;
    height: 399px;
    left: 116px;
    top: 361px;

    background: #1A1B21;

}

.name-text {
    width: 178.06px;
    height: 25.81px;
    top: 382px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.pos {
    width: 178.06px;
    height: 14.19px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12.8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: #F3BF99;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

small {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}

.e-button{
 box-sizing: border-box;
/* Auto layout */
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 9px 13px 9px 11px;
gap: 8px;
width: 247px;
height: 34px;
left: 151px;
top: 469px;

/* white */

background: #FFFFFF;
/* gray/300 */

border: 1px solid #D1D5DB;
/* shadow/sm */

box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
border-radius: 6px;
margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created a little example for you that somewhat gives you what you need. Of course, you can still adjust a few things.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jamyyh

I **only** made changes inside `Info.css`, so just take a look at this file.